# executable JAR file not showing resources

Tags: java, jar

i created an executable JAR file using eclipse.. I have resources in the project folder that 
does not appear when the frame is open..I mean when i double-click on the JAR file. More 
so,After I try to delete the  JAR file I get a warning that the JAR file is being used on the 
Java Se platform .How can I eliminate this problem other than using  a resource loader class?

Comment: How do you load your resources? Are the resources located in the project folder or in the src directory?

Comment: the resources are in the project folder .

Comment: You should place resources that should be included into the Jar into the src folder. That allows you to load the via getResource(..).

Comment: by source folder i hope you mean the folder containing  my class files in  my  workspace....It is in the project folder ..All the resources load when I run it in eclipse but not after I  create the runnable JAR file.. I also found out that putting the executable JAR file and the resources into the same folder other than the project folder ,it loads the resources...But I don't get why It doesn't make an archive file including the resources..

Answer (score 2):

Some times when we run a jar file the resources gets used by jvm and they are not released due to this we cant delete the jar file.So trying killing the processes from the task manager so that you can delete the jar file.For me killing explorer.exe worked.Try killing that process andf then try deleteing jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Use ClassLoader to get the InputStream if your resources is in the source folder.

```
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(String name);
```

Close your application before you delete the JAR file. Or explicitly exit your application with the following code.

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: i set the default close operation for the frame as JFrame.exit_on_ close yet it won't close after i make the executable JAR file

Answer (score 1):

There can be a possibility that the resources are not exported at all. Sometimes it happens that you need to tick the check box against each resource name and then hit finish while exporting it with Eclipse.

Also, please check that there is no warnings when the export process is finished.

Kill all the java.exe and javaw.exe process from task manager and then try to delete.

Comment: i tried closing the  java.exe  with task manager and tried deleting it afterwards yet it did not delete..